# lodash assign key value pair

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash, vuejs2

How do transform this

```
[ { '1491926400000': 222 }, { '1491926400000': 489 } ]
```

to this:

```
[ { date: '1491926400000', count: 222 }, { date: '1491926400000', count: 489 } ]
```

I have tried with 'reduce' and 'transform' using lodash but not going anywhere with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution using `Array#map`.

```js
var arr = [{ '1491926400000': 222 }, { '1491926400000': 489 }],
    res = arr.map(v => Object.assign({}, ...Object.keys(v).map(c => ({ date: c, count: v[c]}))));
    
    console.log(res);
```

Comment: The structure isn't the same as the OP's desired structure. This also might be a bit overwhelming to a beginner, and explanation would help. (Also, you can use spread syntax instead of `Object.assign` )

Comment: @AndrewLi Didn't notice that. Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I don't really care, I'm going to delete this answer in few minutes anyways xd

Comment: Thanks! that helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
var oldArray = [ { '1491926400000': 222 }, { '1491926400000': 489 } ];
var newArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++){
  var originObject = oldArray[i];
  for(var key in originObject) {
    var value = originObject[key];
    var obj = {date: key, count: value};
    newArray.push(obj);
  }
}
```

does the transform

Comment: nope. it gives me [ { date: '0', count: { '1491926400000': 222 } },
  { date: '1', count: { '1491926400000': 489 } } ]

Comment: yeah, i seen the failure and edited it. now it works

Answer (score 0):

Here's a neat solution using `lodash/fp` (curried functions / data last):

```
const mapData = map(
  flowRight(
    zipObject(['date', 'count']),   // { date: '1491926400000', count: 222 }
    flatten,                        // ['1491926400000', 222]
    toPairs                         // [ ['1491926400000', 222] ]
  )
)
```

Same thing in regular `lodash`:

```
const mapData = (data) => map(data, (o) =>
  zipObject(['date', 'count'], flatten(toPairs(o)))
)
```

Usage for either:

```
mapData([ { '1491926400000': 222 }, { '1491926400000': 489 } ])

// [ { date: '1491926400000', count: 222 }, { date: '1491926400000', count: 489 } ]
```